# How to link async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-api, puppeteer

I'll preface this with I'm still quite fresh to coding and am still learning,

I am attempting to execute a script that uses two async functions with node.js. The first function uses puppeteer to fetch links from a webpage and the second uses googleapi to log that data into a google sheet.

Issue I'm running into is the array I'm fetching from the first function is coming up as undefined for the second.

I believe it's an issue of the second script being executed before the first is complete and can return the data. Any insight or help will be much appreciated.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const grablinks = await page.evaluate(() => {
          //retrieves links
            
    }); 

    await browser.close();
    
    return grabLinks;    
}
const {google} = require('googleapis')
const credentials = require('')

const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email, 
    null, 
    credentials.private_key, 
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
);


client.authorize(function(err,tokens){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else{
        console.log('Connected!');
        gsrun(client);
    }

});
async function gsrun(cl){
    
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: cl});
    const grabLinks = await scrapeProduct();
    const updateOptions = {
        spreadsheetId: '',
        range: '',
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        resource: { values :grabLinks}
    };

    let res = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.update(updateOptions);

}
```

I run into the following error when I execute:

ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.url - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 50

50 referring to the end of client.authorize(function(err){

Comment: Where are you calling `scrapeProduct`? As presented, the code should throw an error that `grabLinks` is undefined. Please [edit] the post to share your actual code as a [mcve].

Comment: Is the code in the post currently the *actual code being tested*?

Comment: @danh yes it is

Comment: So I think that means the question has nothing to do with linking async functions, or the puppeteer functions. It's about google auth, and should be rewritten to present all of the info about the auth problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please, learn more about [Scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).
2. Your function `scrapeProduct` never executes.

Change your `gsrun` function to this:

```
async function gsrun(cl,url){
    
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: cl});
    let grabLinks = await scrapeProduct(url);
    const updateOptions = {
        spreadsheetId: '',
        range: '',
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        resource: { values :grabLinks}
    };

    let res = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.update(updateOptions);

}
```

And then run `gsrun` with `client` and your needed `url` inside client.authorize's callback as your wrote.

Comment: I tried this and was met with a new error of 'ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.url'

Comment: @LloydWalker please, update your code to show how exactly you run new `gsrun` function. I think, that there is something with your url. It should be like `gsrun(client,'http://example.com/');`

Answer (score -1):

First, you've only defined `scrapeProduct` and aren't calling it:

```js
async function gsrun(cl){
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: cl});

    const grabLinks = await scrapeProduct(url); // <--- This

    const updateOptions = {
        spreadsheetId: '',
        range: '',
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        resource: { values: grabLinks}
    };
    let res = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.update(updateOptions);
}
```

However, this will still error out. This is because you've defined `scrapeProduct` to be asynchronous (and `await` won't work because `scrapeProduct` isn't returning a promise) so `updateOptions.resource` will have the undefined value.

You can fix this by making sure `scrapeProduct` returns a promise:

```js
function scrapeProduct(url) {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false
        });
    
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        const grablinks = await page.evaluate(() => {
              //retrieves links
            
        }); 

        await browser.close();
    
        resolve(grabLinks);
    }); 
}
```

Now, calling `await scrapeProduct(url)` inside `gsrun()` will work as the code won't execute further until `grabLinks` is returned from `scrapeProduct`

Comment: The puppeteer functions return promises. Wrapping them in a new Promise is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @danh I've updated the script with the error at the end